# Safe speed for dowloading Ubuntu OS file

Tags: ubuntu, download, bittorrent

I wish to download Ubuntu 18.04 desktop version.  Very slow speed takes more time; I know that.  But which speed is considered as the safe speed for downloading Ubuntu? While using BitTorrent, is there any separate speed for downloading or uploading **safely**?  Does it depend on the type of processor? what should I consider? Is high speed here also 'fatal'?

Comment: What do you understand by *safely* here?

Comment: Downloading without any errors.

Comment: The downloading speed should have no influence on the integrity of the downloaded files.  The bittorrent client will take care of that.  So wether you download as fast as your computer can handle or only a couple of hundred bytes per second:  The downloaded files will be the same.  The only issue you will be facing when downloading "too fast" will be that browsing the web at the same time will be sloooooow....

Comment: That is what I was trying to tell you: ANY speed is safe.

Comment: Make sure to compare checksums at the end (Torrent clients will usually do that automatically for you) and you'll be fine no matter what speed you use.

Answer (score 1):

Any network speed is "safe".

At the network layer, TCP packets include a checksum so any corrupted packet will be discarded and resent.

At the application layer, you can verify manually the checksum (e.g. MD5) of a downloaded ISO file by using the command

```
md5sum yourfile.iso
```

and see if the output is identical to the value shown in the downloads webpage. But most of the time this is unnecessary. The BitTorrent protocol even does such a check automatically (using SHA-1 hashing algorithm) so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't upvote due to my low reputation.

Comment: No worries, but you can (and should) mark an answer as "accepted" so that other people can see which questions are solved.